# How to swipe the same Fragment multiple times using ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I want to use a `ViewPager` in order to swipe through Multiple `Fragments`, all this `fragments` are related to the same `Layout` so that I want to swipe *the same Fragment* multiple times like in the following pic:

[image]

as in the picture it's the same fragment but with different data assigned to it.

I'm using the regular page adapter:

```
public class LightPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public LightPageAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    public Fragment getItem(int i) {

        switch (i) {
        case 0:
            // Fragment for Center side
            return new Light_Center_frag();
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return 1;

    }

}
```

I want to handle **two** points when doing that :

**1-** the number of fragments to swipe will be dynamic(got in the run_time).

**2-** I don't want to just change the page contents while swiping, but I do want to obtain the swiping sense as in the following image:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing how you obtain the data that you want displayed in the fragments, you could try to use a Bundle when instantiating the fragments.

`Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putExtra(KEY, someData);`

and then

```
Fragment fragment = new Light_Center_frag();
fragment.setArguments(args);
return fragment;
```

In your fragment then you can call

```
getArguments();
```

to retrieve that Bundle and work with whatever is in there.